# Express a matrix as the product of two matrices, with the smallest common dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a general way to find out the minimum $a$ such that a matrix, $M$, of dimensions $m\times n$, can be expressed as the product of two matrices $A$ of dimensions $m\times a$ and $B$ of dimensions $a\times n$?

I know that this factorization is possible when $a$ is $M$'s rank (as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization)), but I am interested in the minimum such $a$---and it seems to me that sometimes $a$ must be possibly smaller than $M$'s rank. (But perhaps I am wrong about this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank *is* the minimum $a$ (except possibly if the rank is $0$, at which point the minimum $a$ might still be $1$, depending on your attitude towards empty matrices).

Given a natural number $b<a$, let $A$ be an $m\times b$ matrix and $B$ a $b\times n$ matrix. Then the ranks of $A$ and $B$ are both less than or equal to $b$, which means that $AB$ has rank at most $b$, and therefore cannot possibly be equal to $M$.

Comment: Right, of course, thanks about this. I will accept it in ... 2 minutes, apparently :) A related question (which I am happy to ask separately) would be if it is possible to find approximations to M with a product of lower rank matrices. Something like a rank-distortion function.

Comment: @Schiphol Depends on what exactly you mean by "approximation", but yes. For instance, by using the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) and just discarding the "lower ranked" columns from $U$ and $V$ (and multiplying $\Sigma$ into one of them). If you want more details, it's probably best you ask a separate question.